# How to set up different databases / database adapters for multiple versions in Apigility?

Tags: database, rest, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

In Apigility

> DB-Connected services allow [...] to specify a database adapter [...]

(see the [REST Service Tutorial](https://apigility.org/documentation/intro/first-rest-service) in the documentation).

"DB-Connected" services provide `Database Settings`, where the adapter can be assigned. And every adapter "knows", which credentials to use and which database to connect.

I created a "Code-Connected" REST service and want the versions `V1` and `V2` to use separate databases. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use multiple DB adapters, one simply need

1. to create an appropriate configuration block in the (`global.php` for the generall setting like `driver` and `local.php` for the credentials) -- it can be done manually or over the Apugility GUI (`Dashboard -> Database Adapters`)

**global.php**

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'adapters' => array(
            'DB\\myapi_v1' => array(
                'driver' => 'Pdo',
                'driver_options' => array(
                    1002 => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\'',
                ),
                'pdodriver' => 'mysql',
            ),
            'DB\\myapi_v2' => array(
                ...
            ),
        ),
    ),
    ...
);
```

**local.php**

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'adapters' => array(
            'DB\\myproject_v1' => array(
                'username' => 'root',
                'password' => 'pwd',
                'dbname' => 'myproject_v1',
                'host' => 'localhost',
            ),
            'DB\\myproject_v2' => array(
                ...
            ),
        ),
    ),
    ...
);
```

2. to set this adapter instead of the default `Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter`, e.g. using [`ZfcBase\Mapper`](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcBase/tree/master/src/ZfcBase/Mapper) (here an example from an application, where the adapter gets set in the factory for the `service` class; a `service` is here the layer between the `controller`/`resource` and the `DB mapper`):

**[myproject]/module/Portfolio/src/Portfolio/V1/Rest/Image/ImageServiceFactory.php**

```
namespace Portfolio\V1\Rest\Image;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class ImageServiceFactory implements FactoryInterface {

    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceManager) {
        $mapper = new ImageMapper;
        $mapper->setDbAdapter($serviceManager->get('DB\\myproject_v1'));
        $mapper->setEntityPrototype($serviceManager->get('Portfolio\V1\Rest\Image\ImageEntity'));
        $mapper->getHydrator()->setUnderscoreSeparatedKeys(false);
        $service = new ImageService();
        $service->setMapper($mapper);
        return $service;
    }

}
```